# JSON with too many characters error

Tags: json

I am building an application that I am dumping the data from one table into a json object. When I try to use this json object via angular I dont see the data. So I took the data from the json object and ran it in a parser and was told that there are too many characters in my json object. What is this limit?

Part 2, if this is the case, any ideas on how I could break up the data? Thanks

Comment: Some information -- any information -- would be helpful.

Comment: I can paste the json object if that is what you would like to see

Comment: If you can paste the JSON object, it isn't too many characters.

Comment: Well I spit the json out to a blank page. Copied it and pretty it up. Saved it and now instead of calling the data from the database I am loading the file. That seems to work better